# Cycle through a List of Words on Hover using CSS | With Pause and Click States?

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, hover

I've been following this tutorial by Marry Lou on Cycling images on hover:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/09/how-to-create-a-fast-hover-slideshow-with-css3/

Very nice, however what I want to do is do the exact same thing using only TEXT. That is, a word is there, and when the user hovers over it, it cycles through different words or phrases.

So far I've reached the point where I can achieve somewhat of the same effect using jsfiddle, but I don't know if this is the best practice since the words don't maintain their "hover" functionality when all of them are finally done (notice that eventually it just stops cycling).

Jfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/XavierTheGreat/v1vvxxm4/2/

HTML

```
    <div class="hs-wrapper">

  <div class="swapme" alt="div1">
    <h1>
  BOLD
  </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="swapme" alt="div2">
    <h1>
  DRAMATIC
  </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="swapme" alt="div3">
    <h1>
ENGAGED
</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="swapme" alt="div4">
    <h1>
FEARLESS
</h1>
  </div>



  <div class="hs-overlay">
    <span><strong>I AM</strong></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.hs-wrapper .swapme {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: showMe .8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.hs-wrapper:hover .swapme {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes showMe {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  12.5% {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  25% {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

.hs-wrapper .swapme:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 9;
}

.hs-wrapper .swapme:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  z-index: 8;
}

.hs-wrapper .swapme:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  z-index: 7;
}

.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  z-index: 6;
}
```

It also looks pretty ugly when first run with all the text appearing at once. Is there a way to:

1. Show just ONE word which starts the cycling?
2. Have the hover states separate and not overlap each other while hovering?
3. Keep the cycling going until the user moves the mouse away, but when that area is hovered on again it resumes? I don't want it to be left on a blank space, a word should ALWAYS be visible whether it's hovered on or not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of errors with your code, you had used `img` at one place instead of `.swapme`.
Check the below mentioned working snippet.

**Snippet**

```css
.hs-wrapper .swapme {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 25%;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  background-color: white;
}
.hs-wrapper {
  height: 25%;
  width: 25%;
}
.hs-wrapper:hover .swapme {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes showMe {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  12.5% {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  25% {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
.hs-wrapper .swapme:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 9;
}
.hs-wrapper .swapme:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  z-index: 8;
}
.hs-wrapper .swapme:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  z-index: 7;
}
.hs-wrapper .swapme:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  z-index: 6;
}
.hs-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  //box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3) inset;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s alternate;
  text-align: center;
}
.hs-wrapper:hover .hs-overlay {
  opacity: 0.8;
  //box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3) inset;

}
```

```html
<div class="hs-wrapper">
  <div class="swapme" alt="div1">
    <h1>
  BOLD
  </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="swapme" alt="div2">
    <h1>
  DRAMATIC
  </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="swapme" alt="div3">
    <h1>
      ENGAGED
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="swapme" alt="div4">
    <h1>
      FEARLESS
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hs-overlay">
    <span><strong>I AM</strong></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome! You nailed it! Thank you! So say I wanted to add more phrases or words do I just add another div and add another nth child?

Once again you rock!

Comment: @XavierTheGreat : Yes, you keep adding a corresponding div and nth child css for each additional word, and try optimizing the animation time, since as the words increase, the animation time of 0.8 seconds will start to appear too fast.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey again so I just noticed that after trying to add three more some of the words no longer appear. Any observations or guesses?

Here's the JSfiddle btw and I played around with the timing but still can't get it to show all of them

https://jsfiddle.net/v1vvxxm4/50/